# Creating for-loop to run multiple t-tests between multiple columns of 2 data sets in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, analysis

just wondering how I would go about running multiple t-tests between two data sets without having to run the t-test code for each column individually. I know that's vague, so I'll try my best to elaborate:

I started with a single data set of 50 rows and 30 columns. The rows represent individual patients while each column represents expression level of a certain gene for each patient (row). I have separated the data set evenly to create 2 groups: long-term survivors and short-term survivors. I want to run 2-sample t-tests between the two groups for each gene, without having to plug in all the numbers for each group and each gene. What I currently am doing looks like this:

```
long_term_survivor_Gene1 = [0.38,0.78,0.94,0.32,-0.8,-1.03]
short_term_survivor_Gene1 = [0.35,0.05,-0.88,-0.32,-2.13,-1.97]
## I used more samples than that, but I shortened it for brevity
stats.ttest_ind(long_term_survivor_Gene1,short_term_survivor_Gene1)
```

Now, I spoke with my professor and he suggested using a for-loop to be able to do this for every gene (not just Gene1 individually) using one simple block of code. He didn't go into much detail, so is this possible for my data set? Thank you for any help and please let me know if there is any further info you may need in order to help, I'm new to coding in general.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm

Comment: Wouldn’t it make more sense to use a completely randomized block design an compute an anova table?

Comment: Since I'm not too familiar with randomized block design (other than the general idea), I didn't want to go ahead and use it here. Plus, the point of these t-tests is to determine if there is a statistical difference between the expression of different genes in long-term and short-term survivors. But I'll still look into it further and try it out - thanks for the help!

Comment: I second @DJK. Afterwards, you can do a multiple comparison of means with, e.g., Tukey HSD.